# What is Empty in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I create a customer table and for the column called as loan

I pass null for 1 row

I pass '' for another row

and when I execute this query

```
SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.loans IS EMPTY
```

I get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **IS EMPTY** operator is the logical equivalent of **IS NULL**, but for collections.

Queries can use **IS EMPTY** operator or **IS NOT EMPTY** to check whether a collection association path resolves to an empty collection or has at least one value.

We can use the **EMPTY** to check if a property is empty.

The following JPQL shows how to use **EMPTY** to get employee withno projects.

```
Query unassignedQuery = 
    em.createQuery("SELECT e " +
                   "FROM Employee e " +
                   "WHERE e.projects IS EMPTY");
```

According to the JPA 2.1 spec:

> If there are no associated entities for a multi-valued relationship of
> an entity fetched from the database, the persistence provider is
> responsible for returning an empty collection as the value of the
> relationship.

[Reference](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/jpql-is-empty.html)

Comment: so it check if the attribute(which is a collection) is empty or not?

Comment: this "the persistence provider is responsible for returning an empty collection as the value of the relationship." So it will return empty collection.